# Regex to get value from solr FQ local Tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex, solr

I am using Aajx Solr for a building application, now am trying apply additive method in the facet selection which is working, with also FQ value am able to append on bread crumbs.

The issues is i just want only value should be display in breadcrumbs

Ie.

```
 fq: "{!tag=places}places:\"usa\";  // Printing Value in breadcrumbs  "{!tag=false}places:"usa"
```

and

> "{!tag=organisations}organisations:\"abcefg\";  // Printing Value  in breadcrumbs "{!tag=organisations}organisations:"abcefg"

i want only value should be printed 
like

> "{!tag=organisations}organisations:\"abcefg\";  // Printing Value  in breadcrumbs "abcefg"
>     "{!tag=places}places:\"usa\";            // Printing Value in breadcrumbs  "usa"

How do i escape "{!tag=organisations}organisations:" from  the fq only i want quote value should be return.

I tried with

fq[i].toString().replace('organisations', '').replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace('!', '').replace('=', '').replace('false', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '');

but its not right method to get quote values

which regx pattern can be use in this method, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((?<=(\\"))([\w]+)(?=\\")|(?<=")([\w]+)(?="))
```

You can see it in action on your test expression here:

http://rubular.com/r/tL7QvpxrKx